# Blazor WASM suppress 'Found a native function' warning?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am using SQLite in my Blazor WASM app, and it is giving me the following warnings:

```
Found a native function (sqlite3_config) with varargs in e_sqlite3. Calling such functions is not supported, and will fail at runtime. Managed DllImports: ...
```

```
Found a native function (sqlite3_db_config) with varargs in e_sqlite3. Calling such functions is not supported, and will fail at runtime. Managed DllImports: ...
```

Is there a way to suppress these warnings? They are obviously a false positive, since I build and publish just fine. They do not have a Code to suppress with.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to suppress these warnings?

Comment: @Ross Unfortunately, I have not. I will ping you if I ever do!